# Replace Line in File

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I have a text file which I have a BufferedReader read from.

```
String sCurrentLine;

File myFile = new File("/sdcard/file.txt");
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
while ((sCurrentLine = buf.readLine()) != null) {
}
```

What I want to do is read a specific line and then replace it with something else whilst leaving the rest of the file alone. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a temporary file
- Read through the file `file.txt`, write the output to the temporary file making the replacement as necessary
- Close the file
- Delete/backup the original file
- Rename the temporary file to the original file